# How can I do the functions in order: 1. enlarge -> 2. rotate 360 degrees -> 3. resize to before enlargement -> 4. change color (toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

Here is a demo. How can I do the functions in order:
1. enlarge -> 2. rotate 360 degrees -> 3. resize to before enlargement -> 4. change color (toggle)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tlist td div').click(function() {

    $(this).css("z-index", "1000").animate({
      width: '+=90px',
      height: '+=90px',
      fontSize: '300%',
      zIndex: 1000
    }, {
      step: function(now, fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(360deg)');
      },
      duration: 'slow'
    }).animate({
      width: '-=90px',
      height: '-=90px',
      fontSize: '120%',
      zIndex: 1

    }).toggleClass('changeColor').css("z-index", "1");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 1340px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tlist {
  display: inline;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px 7px;
}

#rightT {
  padding-left: 115px;
}

.tlist th {
  font-size: 160%;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}

.tlist td {
  width: 56px;
  height: 54px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.tlist td div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 45px;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 120%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.tlist td div.changeColor {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: red;
}

#left1,
#left2,
#left5,
#left6,
#left7,
#left8,
#left3,
#left4 {
  text-align: right;
}

#right1,
#right2,
#right3,
#right4,
#right5,
#right6,
#right7,
#right8 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='leftT' class='tlist'>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th id='a1'>1</th>
    <th id='a2'>2</th>
    <th id='a3'>3</th>
    <th id='a4'>4</th>
    <th id='a5'>5</th>
    <th id='a6'>6</th>
    <th id='a7'>7</th>
    <th id='a8'>8</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left1'>15/F</th>
    <td id='f1501'>
      <div>1501</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1502'>
      <div>1502</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1503'>
      <div>1503</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1504'>
      <div>1504</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1505'>
      <div>1505</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1506'>
      <div>1506</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1507'>
      <div>1507</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1508'>
      <div>1508</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right1'>15/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1401'>
      <div>1401</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1402'>
      <div>1402</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1403'>
      <div>1403</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1404'>
      <div>1404</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1405'>
      <div>1405</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1406'>
      <div>1406</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1407'>
      <div>1407</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1408'>
      <div>1408</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1301'>
      <div>1301</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1302'>
      <div>1302</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1303'>
      <div>1303</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1304'>
      <div>1304</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1305'>
      <div>1305</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1306'>
      <div>1306</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1307'>
      <div>1307</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1308'>
      <div>1308</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1201'>
      <div>1201</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1202'>
      <div>1202</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1203'>
      <div>1203</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1204'>
      <div>1204</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1205'>
      <div>1205</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1206'>
      <div>1206</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1207'>
      <div>1207</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1208'>
      <div>1208</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1101'>
      <div>1101</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1102'>
      <div>1102</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1103'>
      <div>1103</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1104'>
      <div>1104</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1105'>
      <div>1105</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1106'>
      <div>1106</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1107'>
      <div>1107</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1108'>
      <div>1108</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left2'>10/F</th>
    <td id='f1001'>
      <div>1001</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1002'>
      <div>1002</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1003'>
      <div>1003</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1004'>
      <div>1004</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1005'>
      <div>1005</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1006'>
      <div>1006</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1007'>
      <div>1007</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1008'>
      <div>1008</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right2'>10/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f901'>
      <div>901</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f902'>
      <div>902</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f903'>
      <div>903</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f904'>
      <div>904</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f905'>
      <div>905</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f906'>
      <div>906</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f907'>
      <div>907</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f908'>
      <div>908</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f801'>
      <div>801</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f802'>
      <div>802</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f803'>
      <div>803</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f804'>
      <div>804</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f805'>
      <div>805</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f806'>
      <div>806</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f807'>
      <div>807</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f808'>
      <div>808</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f701'>
      <div>701</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f702'>
      <div>702</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f703'>
      <div>703</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f704'>
      <div>704</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f705'>
      <div>705</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f706'>
      <div>706</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f707'>
      <div>707</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f708'>
      <div>708</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f601'>
      <div>601</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f602'>
      <div>602</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f603'>
      <div>603</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f604'>
      <div>604</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f605'>
      <div>605</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f606'>
      <div>606</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f607'>
      <div>607</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f608'>
      <div>608</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left3'>5/F</th>
    <td id='f501'>
      <div>501</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f502'>
      <div>502</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f503'>
      <div>503</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f504'>
      <div>504</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f505'>
      <div>505</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f506'>
      <div>506</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f507'>
      <div>507</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f508'>
      <div>508</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right3'>5/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f401'>
      <div>401</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f402'>
      <div>402</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f403'>
      <div>403</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f404'>
      <div>404</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f405'>
      <div>405</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f406'>
      <div>406</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f407'>
      <div>407</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f408'>
      <div>408</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f301'>
      <div>301</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f302'>
      <div>302</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f303'>
      <div>303</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f304'>
      <div>304</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f305'>
      <div>305</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f306'>
      <div>306</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f307'>
      <div>307</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f308'>
      <div>308</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f201'>
      <div>201</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f202'>
      <div>202</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f203'>
      <div>203</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f204'>
      <div>204</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f205'>
      <div>205</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f206'>
      <div>206</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f207'>
      <div>207</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f208'>
      <div>208</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left4'>1/F</th>
    <td id='f101'>
      <div>101</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f102'>
      <div>102</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f103'>
      <div>103</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f104'>
      <div>104</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f105'>
      <div>105</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f106'>
      <div>106</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f107'>
      <div>107</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f108'>
      <div>108</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right4'>1/F</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- Table on Right -->
<table id='rightT' class='tlist'>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th id='b1'>1</th>
    <th id='b2'>2</th>
    <th id='b3'>3</th>
    <th id='b4'>4</th>
    <th id='b5'>5</th>
    <th id='b6'>6</th>
    <th id='b7'>7</th>
    <th id='b8'>8</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left5'>30/F</th>
    <td id='f3001'>
      <div>3001</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3002'>
      <div>3002</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3003'>
      <div>3003</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3004'>
      <div>3004</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3005'>
      <div>3005</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3006'>
      <div>3006</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3007'>
      <div>3007</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3008'>
      <div>3008</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right5'>30/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2901'>
      <div>2901</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2902'>
      <div>2902</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2903'>
      <div>2903</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2904'>
      <div>2904</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2905'>
      <div>2905</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2906'>
      <div>2906</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2907'>
      <div>2907</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2908'>
      <div>2908</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2801'>
      <div>2801</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2802'>
      <div>2802</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2803'>
      <div>2803</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2804'>
      <div>2804</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2805'>
      <div>2805</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2806'>
      <div>2806</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2807'>
      <div>2807</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2808'>
      <div>2808</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2701'>
      <div>2701</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2702'>
      <div>2702</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2703'>
      <div>2703</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2704'>
      <div>2704</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2705'>
      <div>2705</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2706'>
      <div>2706</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2707'>
      <div>2707</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2708'>
      <div>2708</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2601'>
      <div>2601</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2602'>
      <div style='background-color:white;color:black;'>2602</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2603'>
      <div>2603</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2604'>
      <div>2604</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2605'>
      <div>2605</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2606'>
      <div>2606</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2607'>
      <div>2607</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2608'>
      <div>2608</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left6'>25/F</th>
    <td id='f2501'>
      <div>2501</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2502'>
      <div>2502</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2503'>
      <div>2503</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2504'>
      <div>2504</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2505'>
      <div>2505</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2506'>
      <div>2506</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2507'>
      <div>2507</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2508'>
      <div>2508</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right6'>25/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2401'>
      <div>2401</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2402'>
      <div>2402</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2403'>
      <div>2403</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2404'>
      <div>2404</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2405'>
      <div>2405</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2406'>
      <div>2406</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2407'>
      <div>2407</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2408'>
      <div>2408</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2301'>
      <div>2301</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2302'>
      <div>2302</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2303'>
      <div>2303</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2304'>
      <div>2304</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2305'>
      <div>2305</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2306'>
      <div>2306</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2307'>
      <div>2307</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2308'>
      <div>2308</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2201'>
      <div>2201</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2202'>
      <div>2202</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2203'>
      <div>2203</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2204'>
      <div>2204</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2205'>
      <div>2205</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2206'>
      <div>2206</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2207'>
      <div>2207</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2208'>
      <div>2208</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2101'>
      <div>2101</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2102'>
      <div>2102</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2103'>
      <div>2103</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2104'>
      <div>2104</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2105'>
      <div>2105</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2106'>
      <div>2106</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2107'>
      <div>2107</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2108'>
      <div>2108</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left7'>20/F</th>
    <td id='f2001'>
      <div>2001</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2002'>
      <div>2002</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2003'>
      <div>2003</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2004'>
      <div>2004</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2005'>
      <div>2005</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2006'>
      <div>2006</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2007'>
      <div>2007</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2008'>
      <div>2008</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right7'>20/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1901'>
      <div>1901</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1902'>
      <div>1902</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1903'>
      <div>1903</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1904'>
      <div>1904</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1905'>
      <div>1905</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1906'>
      <div>1906</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1907'>
      <div>1907</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1908'>
      <div>1908</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1801'>
      <div>1801</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1802'>
      <div>1802</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1803'>
      <div style='background-color:white;color:black;'>1803</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1804'>
      <div>1804</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1805'>
      <div>1805</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1806'>
      <div>1806</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1807'>
      <div>1807</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1808'>
      <div>1808</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1701'>
      <div>1701</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1702'>
      <div>1702</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1703'>
      <div>1703</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1704'>
      <div>1704</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1705'>
      <div>1705</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1706'>
      <div>1706</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1707'>
      <div>1707</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1708'>
      <div>1708</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left8'>16/F</th>
    <td id='f1601'>
      <div>1601</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1602'>
      <div>1602</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1603'>
      <div>1603</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1604'>
      <div>1604</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1605'>
      <div>1605</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1606'>
      <div>1606</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1607'>
      <div>1607</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1608'>
      <div>1608</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right8'>16/F</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3a4drvg7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

A Simple yet most efficient way of doing this is using **css**.

**A Simple CSS Solution for you using your own fiddle.**

***Updated the Answer as per comment.***

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/0ew6yh6n/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tlist td div').click(function() {
    var t = $(this)
    t.removeClass('changeStyle');
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.addClass('changeStyle');
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 1340px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tlist {
  display: inline;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px 7px;
}

#rightT {
  padding-left: 115px;
}

.tlist th {
  font-size: 160%;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}

.tlist td {
  width: 56px;
  height: 54px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.tlist td div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 45px;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 120%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.tlist td div.changeColor {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: red;
}

#left1,
#left2,
#left5,
#left6,
#left7,
#left8,
#left3,
#left4 {
  text-align: right;
}

#right1,
#right2,
#right3,
#right4,
#right5,
#right6,
#right7,
#right8 {
  text-align: left;
}

@keyframes styleIt {
  0% {}
  25% {
    transform: scale(1.5) rotate(0deg)
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: red;
  }
}

.changeStyle {
  animation: styleIt 1s forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='leftT' class='tlist'>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th id='a1'>1</th>
    <th id='a2'>2</th>
    <th id='a3'>3</th>
    <th id='a4'>4</th>
    <th id='a5'>5</th>
    <th id='a6'>6</th>
    <th id='a7'>7</th>
    <th id='a8'>8</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left1'>15/F</th>
    <td id='f1501'>
      <div>1501</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1502'>
      <div>1502</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1503'>
      <div>1503</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1504'>
      <div>1504</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1505'>
      <div>1505</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1506'>
      <div>1506</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1507'>
      <div>1507</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1508'>
      <div>1508</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right1'>15/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1401'>
      <div>1401</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1402'>
      <div>1402</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1403'>
      <div>1403</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1404'>
      <div>1404</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1405'>
      <div>1405</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1406'>
      <div>1406</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1407'>
      <div>1407</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1408'>
      <div>1408</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1301'>
      <div>1301</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1302'>
      <div>1302</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1303'>
      <div>1303</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1304'>
      <div>1304</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1305'>
      <div>1305</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1306'>
      <div>1306</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1307'>
      <div>1307</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1308'>
      <div>1308</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1201'>
      <div>1201</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1202'>
      <div>1202</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1203'>
      <div>1203</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1204'>
      <div>1204</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1205'>
      <div>1205</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1206'>
      <div>1206</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1207'>
      <div>1207</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1208'>
      <div>1208</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1101'>
      <div>1101</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1102'>
      <div>1102</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1103'>
      <div>1103</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1104'>
      <div>1104</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1105'>
      <div>1105</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1106'>
      <div>1106</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1107'>
      <div>1107</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1108'>
      <div>1108</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left2'>10/F</th>
    <td id='f1001'>
      <div>1001</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1002'>
      <div>1002</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1003'>
      <div>1003</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1004'>
      <div>1004</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1005'>
      <div>1005</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1006'>
      <div>1006</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1007'>
      <div>1007</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1008'>
      <div>1008</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right2'>10/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f901'>
      <div>901</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f902'>
      <div>902</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f903'>
      <div>903</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f904'>
      <div>904</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f905'>
      <div>905</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f906'>
      <div>906</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f907'>
      <div>907</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f908'>
      <div>908</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f801'>
      <div>801</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f802'>
      <div>802</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f803'>
      <div>803</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f804'>
      <div>804</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f805'>
      <div>805</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f806'>
      <div>806</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f807'>
      <div>807</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f808'>
      <div>808</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f701'>
      <div>701</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f702'>
      <div>702</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f703'>
      <div>703</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f704'>
      <div>704</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f705'>
      <div>705</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f706'>
      <div>706</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f707'>
      <div>707</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f708'>
      <div>708</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f601'>
      <div>601</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f602'>
      <div>602</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f603'>
      <div>603</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f604'>
      <div>604</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f605'>
      <div>605</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f606'>
      <div>606</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f607'>
      <div>607</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f608'>
      <div>608</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left3'>5/F</th>
    <td id='f501'>
      <div>501</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f502'>
      <div>502</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f503'>
      <div>503</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f504'>
      <div>504</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f505'>
      <div>505</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f506'>
      <div>506</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f507'>
      <div>507</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f508'>
      <div>508</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right3'>5/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f401'>
      <div>401</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f402'>
      <div>402</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f403'>
      <div>403</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f404'>
      <div>404</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f405'>
      <div>405</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f406'>
      <div>406</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f407'>
      <div>407</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f408'>
      <div>408</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f301'>
      <div>301</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f302'>
      <div>302</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f303'>
      <div>303</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f304'>
      <div>304</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f305'>
      <div>305</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f306'>
      <div>306</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f307'>
      <div>307</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f308'>
      <div>308</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f201'>
      <div>201</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f202'>
      <div>202</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f203'>
      <div>203</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f204'>
      <div>204</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f205'>
      <div>205</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f206'>
      <div>206</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f207'>
      <div>207</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f208'>
      <div>208</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left4'>1/F</th>
    <td id='f101'>
      <div>101</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f102'>
      <div>102</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f103'>
      <div>103</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f104'>
      <div>104</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f105'>
      <div>105</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f106'>
      <div>106</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f107'>
      <div>107</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f108'>
      <div>108</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right4'>1/F</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- Table on Right -->
<table id='rightT' class='tlist'>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th id='b1'>1</th>
    <th id='b2'>2</th>
    <th id='b3'>3</th>
    <th id='b4'>4</th>
    <th id='b5'>5</th>
    <th id='b6'>6</th>
    <th id='b7'>7</th>
    <th id='b8'>8</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left5'>30/F</th>
    <td id='f3001'>
      <div>3001</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3002'>
      <div>3002</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3003'>
      <div>3003</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3004'>
      <div>3004</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3005'>
      <div>3005</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3006'>
      <div>3006</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3007'>
      <div>3007</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f3008'>
      <div>3008</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right5'>30/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2901'>
      <div>2901</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2902'>
      <div>2902</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2903'>
      <div>2903</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2904'>
      <div>2904</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2905'>
      <div>2905</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2906'>
      <div>2906</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2907'>
      <div>2907</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2908'>
      <div>2908</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2801'>
      <div>2801</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2802'>
      <div>2802</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2803'>
      <div>2803</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2804'>
      <div>2804</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2805'>
      <div>2805</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2806'>
      <div>2806</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2807'>
      <div>2807</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2808'>
      <div>2808</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2701'>
      <div>2701</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2702'>
      <div>2702</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2703'>
      <div>2703</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2704'>
      <div>2704</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2705'>
      <div>2705</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2706'>
      <div>2706</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2707'>
      <div>2707</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2708'>
      <div>2708</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2601'>
      <div>2601</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2602'>
      <div style='background-color:white;color:black;'>2602</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2603'>
      <div>2603</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2604'>
      <div>2604</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2605'>
      <div>2605</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2606'>
      <div>2606</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2607'>
      <div>2607</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2608'>
      <div>2608</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left6'>25/F</th>
    <td id='f2501'>
      <div>2501</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2502'>
      <div>2502</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2503'>
      <div>2503</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2504'>
      <div>2504</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2505'>
      <div>2505</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2506'>
      <div>2506</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2507'>
      <div>2507</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2508'>
      <div>2508</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right6'>25/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2401'>
      <div>2401</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2402'>
      <div>2402</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2403'>
      <div>2403</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2404'>
      <div>2404</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2405'>
      <div>2405</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2406'>
      <div>2406</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2407'>
      <div>2407</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2408'>
      <div>2408</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2301'>
      <div>2301</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2302'>
      <div>2302</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2303'>
      <div>2303</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2304'>
      <div>2304</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2305'>
      <div>2305</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2306'>
      <div>2306</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2307'>
      <div>2307</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2308'>
      <div>2308</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2201'>
      <div>2201</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2202'>
      <div>2202</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2203'>
      <div>2203</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2204'>
      <div>2204</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2205'>
      <div>2205</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2206'>
      <div>2206</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2207'>
      <div>2207</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2208'>
      <div>2208</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f2101'>
      <div>2101</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2102'>
      <div>2102</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2103'>
      <div>2103</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2104'>
      <div>2104</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2105'>
      <div>2105</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2106'>
      <div>2106</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2107'>
      <div>2107</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2108'>
      <div>2108</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left7'>20/F</th>
    <td id='f2001'>
      <div>2001</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2002'>
      <div>2002</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2003'>
      <div>2003</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2004'>
      <div>2004</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2005'>
      <div>2005</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2006'>
      <div>2006</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2007'>
      <div>2007</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f2008'>
      <div>2008</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right7'>20/F</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1901'>
      <div>1901</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1902'>
      <div>1902</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1903'>
      <div>1903</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1904'>
      <div>1904</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1905'>
      <div>1905</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1906'>
      <div>1906</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1907'>
      <div>1907</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1908'>
      <div>1908</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1801'>
      <div>1801</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1802'>
      <div>1802</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1803'>
      <div style='background-color:white;color:black;'>1803</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1804'>
      <div>1804</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1805'>
      <div>1805</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1806'>
      <div>1806</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1807'>
      <div>1807</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1808'>
      <div>1808</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td id='f1701'>
      <div>1701</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1702'>
      <div>1702</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1703'>
      <div>1703</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1704'>
      <div>1704</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1705'>
      <div>1705</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1706'>
      <div>1706</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1707'>
      <div>1707</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1708'>
      <div>1708</div>
    </td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id='left8'>16/F</th>
    <td id='f1601'>
      <div>1601</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1602'>
      <div>1602</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1603'>
      <div>1603</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1604'>
      <div>1604</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1605'>
      <div>1605</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1606'>
      <div>1606</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1607'>
      <div>1607</div>
    </td>
    <td id='f1608'>
      <div>1608</div>
    </td>
    <th id='right8'>16/F</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this Helps you if you want **`jQuery`** solution please do ask, ty..

Comment: @AwsmeSandy your link is not updated, I can't see the changes bro.

Comment: @AwsmeSandy Nyz work bro, it's a little bit slow but nice work keep it up. :)

Comment: There is no rotation if second click

Comment: @loeghy10 that is becasue we are toggling the class. as per your **Q** - change color (toggle)

Comment: @loeghy10 **Updated the answer for you**